# Angularjs call directive in another controller

Tags: angularjs, events, resize, call, directive

```
    abcModule.directive('resize', function ($window) {
        return function (scope, element) {alert('ad');
        var w = angular.element($window);
        scope.getWindowDimensions = function () {
            return { 'h': w.height(), 'w': w.width() };

        };
        scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
           //scope.windowWidth = newValue.w;
          // alert('cal');
            scope.wrapHeight = $('#wrapper').height();
            scope.calcHeight = scope.windowHeight - scope.wrapHeight;           
            if(scope.calcHeight > 80){
                scope.isScroll = false;
            }
            else{
                scope.isScroll = true;
            }
            scope.style = function () {
                return { 
                    'height': (newValue.h - 100) + 'px',
                    //'width': (newValue.w - 100) + 'px' 
                };
            };

        }, true);
        w.bind('resize', function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
})
```

Now i would like to call above resize method inside a another function based on certain condition, Can anyone help me on this ???

Comment: Please describe with more concrete details what you're trying to do. A long code block plus one vague question isn't enough to get helpful answers.